# Ansible task command with credentials

Tags: ansible

I am wondering if during an Ansible task is it safe to send credentials (password, api key) in a command line task?

No one on the remote server should see the command line (and even less credentials).

Thank you.

Comment: Define "safe" - are you, for example, saving the credentials in a Git repo?

Comment: By safe I mean that an user (rooted or not) on the remote host should never see the command line with these credentials (history, or logging).
Credentials will be stored on Git repo (private) but I just want information concerning only remote side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not trusting remote server - you should never expose sensitive credentials to it, since anyone having root access on that server can easily intercept traffic, files and memory allocated by you on that server. The easiest way for someone to get you secrets would be to dump temporary files that ansible creating to do it's job on remote server, since it requires only privileges of the user you are connecting as!

There is a special environment variable called `ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1` used to troubleshoot problems. It should give you an idea about what information is actually stored by ansible on remote disks, even for a brief seconds. I've executed

```
ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1 ansible -m command -a "echo 'SUPER_SECRET_INFO'" -i 127.0.0.1, all
```

command on my machine to see files ansible creates on remote machine. After it's execution i see temporary file in my home directory, named `~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1492114067.19-55553396244878/command.py`

So let's grep out secret info:

```
grep SUPER_SECRET ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1492114067.19-55553396244878/command.py
```

Result:

> ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS = '{"ANSIBLE_MODULE_ARGS": {"_ansible_version": "2.2.2.0", "_ansible_selinux_special_fs": ["fuse", "nfs", "vboxsf", "ramfs"], "_ansible_no_log": false, "_ansible_module_name": "command", "_raw_params": "echo \'SUPER_SECRET_INFO\'", "_ansible_verbosity": 0, "_ansible_syslog_facility": "LOG_USER", "_ansible_diff": false, "_ansible_debug": false, "_ansible_check_mode": false}}'

As you can see - nothing is safe from the prying eyes! So if you are really concerned about your secrets - don't use anything critical on suspected hosts, use one time passwords, keys or revokable tokens to mitigate this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how paranoid are you about this credentials. In general: no, it is not safe.

I guess root user on remote host can see anything.
For example, run `strace -f -p$(pidof -s sshd)` on remote host and try to execute any command via ssh.

By default Ansible write all invocations to syslog on remote host, you can set `no_log: no` for task to avoid this.